# ”Error establishing a database connection" with Amazon EC2/CloudFront/LoadBalancer

Tags: wordpress, database-connection, amazon-cloudfront

We have following configuration flow for our wordpress on AWS(not bitnami):

CloudFront -> LoadBalance -> EC2

While I am working with some test DNS(example: dev.mywordpress.com) with above flow, the site is working without any issue.

When I am moving the above DNS into www.mywordpress.com(this DNS is already hosted with a different server - non wordpress - which we are trying to replace with AWS and wordpress), the site is giving error "Error establishing a database connection".

In this case, we are just renaming "dev.mywordpress.com" with "www.mywordpress.com" along with some other necessary changes like siteUrl and updating cName from CloudFront.

Any idea - what making this database connection error?

Comment: I think you should check the `aws security group`

Comment: Hello Jared,

Thank you for your suggestion. Can you please suggest more specifically - what SG should I check?

With the same SG, dev.mywordpress.com is working fine.

Comment: If the SG is ok, I recommened you to check the IP, because CloudFront is CDN so it will change the target IP.

Comment: Restarting the instance did the job. 

Thank you for your responses anyway